# How to display RangeType values as a table in twig?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I would like to display the values in `tmp` ,`tmp2` ,`tmp3` as a table using the `list.html.twig` file.  I tried using a form to display the values but I can't understand how to pass the values to the twig file to make a table containing these values (name , age , task)

The only way I can display these values is by using echo for each value in `all__users`
Here is the code of my controlleur:

```
/**
* @Route("/list", name="list_Users")
*/  
public function list()
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name', RangeType::class)
        ->add('age', RangeType::class)
        ->add('task', RangeType::class)
       
        ->getForm();

    $all_Users = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class)
        ->findAll();
    
    if (!$all_Users) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'database is empty or there was an error connecting to db'
        );

    }


    for  ($x =0; $x < count($all_Users); $x++ ){
        echo "$x";
        $tmp = $all_Users[$x]->getName();
        $tmp2 =$all_Users[$x]->getAge();
        $tmp3 = $all_Users[$x]->getTask();
        
        echo "$tmp ,$tmp2 , $tmp3 \n";
        echo "\n";

    }

 
    return $this->render('User/list.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
     
}
```

Comment: can you see how your passing to `render('path/to/file.html.twig', ['key'=>'value'])`, do the same instead of echo'ing

Answer (score 0):

This should work. But you need to render 'users' too. Or you could write your own extension.

```
<tr>
{% for property_title in users|keys %} 
    <td>{{ property_title }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% for user in users%}
    <tr>
        {% for field in users|keys %}
            <td>{{ attribute(user, field) }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want render form as table. Look [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html). It should answer all your questions.